# Link in "Help and Improvement" is redundant

Tags: discussion, help-improvement

In the "Help and Improvement" queue there is a link to the original question (the question title itself) AND **another** link to it, simply called "link" (right above the "question is very low quality" link).

> [image]

Isn't it redundant?

Comment: The link is more findable then, esp. since the other review queues also have a link there.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit redundant having two links, but so what?

That's how all of the review queues look, not just the *Help and Improvement* one. They have the "link" link to take you to the post that you're currently reviewing, not all of which are questions. For answers it's the *only* link to the post.

It doesn't seem like it's worth adding a check on post type to determine whether or not that link should show, just because in some (most?) cases it's redundant.

Comment: I see. I just noticed that, I wanted to contribute.